# Cannot clone mercurial server from http URL

Tags: macos, mercurial

I can clone my project from a mercurial repository via SSH connection.

```
hg clone --debug ssh://user@192.168.0.4/mercurial/MyAndroidStudioProject
```

But I cannot clone this same project via HTTP connection.

```
hg clone --debug http://192.268.0.4:8888/MyAndroidStudioProject/
```

The process hangs after this log.

```
using http://192.268.0.4:8888/MyAndroidStudioProject/
sending capabilities command
destination directory: MyAndroidStudioProject
query 1; heads
sending batch command
requesting all changes
sending getbundle command
```

I can access this HTTP URL from a web browser but I cannot clone from terminal and AndroidStudio. May I know the root cause of this problem and how can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you serving your repository from the server? Sounds like you may be trying to access it over a regular Apache service, which will not Just Work. The server must be able to respond to mercurial-specific requests (like `getbundle` in your log), which requires some setup from you.

The easiest way to serve a repo over HTTP: Use SSH to log on to your server, cd to your repo and type [`hg serve`](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html#sec:collab:serve). This is enough to clone over HTTP, though you probably don't want to leave it running long-term-- and it will only give you read-only access. For more functionality, see the section [Serving over HTTP using CGI](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html#sec:collab:cgi) in the Mercurial book. It doesn't sound like a piece of cake, so my advice would be to find another way to get your job done.

The Mercurial book discusses your options in some detail in [this chapter](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the solution already, it was because of office firewall setting block this activities. Therefore, I cannot clone the project via http connection. Thanks.